# Run BAT file from Adobe AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, batch-file, air, air2

To package an .air file into a native installer you have to use a batch program called `adt`.

The command on `Windows` will look something like this:

> C:\Users\jisaacks>"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder
>   4\sdks\4.1.0\bin\adt" -package -target
>   native "D:\DEV\Flex4\Workspaces\AIR
>   Native Packager\AIRNIP\AIRNIP.exe"
>   "D:\DEV\Flex4\Workspaces\AIR Native
>   Packager\AIRNIP\AIRNIP.air"

I am trying to author a program in AIR that does this for you. Basically you drag/drop an .air file into it and it packages it into a native installer.

Well It gave me an `Error #3219` error, which I looked up and found this:

> AIR on Windows does not allow you to
>   run .bat files directly. Windows .bat
>   files are executed by the command
>   interpreter application (cmd.exe).
>   When you invoke a .bat file, this
>   command application can interpret
>   arguments passed to the command as
>   additional applications to launch. A
>   malicious injection of extra
>   characters in the argument string
>   could cause cmd.exe to execute a
>   harmful or insecure application. For
>   example, without proper data
>   validation, your AIR application may
>   call myBat.bat myArguments
>   c:/evil.exe. The command application
>   would launch the evil.exe application
>   in addition to running your batch
>   file.
>
> If you call the start() method with a
>   .bat file, the NativeProcess object
>   throws an exception. The message
>   property of the Error object contains
>   the string "Error #3219: The
>   NativeProcess could not be started."

I am wondering if there is a possible work around or if I have hit a brick wall?

Comment: it's also true for .cmd files

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have hit a brick wall, at least with trying to do this in Adobe Air. Executing batch files can be a huge security hole, as your post claimed.

Are you trying to do this in Air for portability, or would you be able to use some other language?

I suggest trying to code this in python. Using the `subprocess`library can help a lot.

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

Serge Jespers (Adobe Evangelist) (http://www.webkitchen.be/) has done exactly this,
I think you should try to contact him for the details.

I helped him build a first solution by creating a windows executable which executed any bat file you specified, later he changed it by calling the java application (adt) directly which works fine as well.

He'll be very happy to help you.

**UPDATE:**
You can download the Package Assitant Pro right here: http://www.webkitchen.be/package-assistant-pro/

Comment: PS: I have notified him of this message so he can get back to you when he is available.

Comment: You can still try to contact him, he'd be happy to answer all your questions :)